# Is it okay if my flight ticket has one extra word in my surname?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, passports

My surname previously had 2 words, X Y, which is how it is currently listed on my flight ticket. However, I recently become a citizen of a different country and obtained a new passport. In my new passport the last word in my surname is discarded, so my surname is currently only X. I also surrendered my old passport, so I can not use that to travel.

My first/given name is still the same.

Do I need to contact my airlines and request them to adjust my surname? Or is it fine to leave it as it is?

Comment: Which passport will you use?

Comment: Also, what are your citizenships and what countries are you flying from and to? This is the probably the kind of edge case where some agents will not even blink and accept it, and others will make a fuss, it’s hard to tell. If your travel involves any kind of advance information to the destination country it’s more likely to be a problem.

Comment: Why don't you just use the passport that you had while you were booking. It should still be valid.

Comment: I should have clarified this in my question, apologies. I surrendered my old passport, so only my new passport is in my possession.

Comment: Does the airline require you to enter passport details before the flight? Do they allow you to enter a different name than the one on the ticket? If you are flying internationally, especially to the US, I would very strongly recommend you get the ticket amended. For domestic travel the chances of going through are probably higher, but I would still recommend updating the ticket to avoid any potential issues.

Comment: @jcaron Yes, the airline requires me to enter details and no, I cannot enter a different name. I am flying internationally, to Europe. Based on what you said, I think I will contact my airlines and change my name to prevent any potential issues. Thanks!

Comment: To reassure you. I have 2 names in passport, but I book always with one name, and I never had problem. More care should be done in case of API (advanced Passenger Information) required on some countries. This is usually a different step and can be done separately. In such case you should use exact passport number and exact names on such passport (but I'm not sure about names with characters outside most common characters in latin scripts). [These names can be changed without problem, but there is a cut-off date, and then airline should send to the required authorities the data)